# Loop through loop React Material UI Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-hooks

Hi guys I don't now why this code is not working, I **want to iterate a object** (paleogenome.data) and create a CardHeader forEach one:

```
              {
              Object.keys(paleogenome.data).forEach(function (key){

                console.log(paleogenome.data[key].NAME); //PRINT WORKS FINE
                console.log(paleogenome.data[key].FULL_NAME); //PRINT WORKS FINE

                <CardHeader
                  avatar={
                    <Avatar aria-label="recipe" className={classes.avatar}>
                      R
                    </Avatar>
                  }
                  action={
                    <IconButton
                      href={`/buscador?` + paleogenome.data[key].NAME}
                    >
                      <ArrowForwardIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  }
                  title={paleogenome.data[key].NAME}
                  subheader={paleogenome.data[key].FULL_NAME}
                />


              })
             }

            </Card>
          </Grid>
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

`forEach` doesn't return anything, use `map` instead:

```
Object.keys(paleogenome.data).map(key => {
    return (
      <CardHeader
        avatar={
          <Avatar aria-label="recipe" className={classes.avatar}>
            R
          </Avatar>
        }
        action={
          <IconButton href={`/buscador?` + paleogenome.data[key].NAME}>
            <ArrowForwardIcon />
          </IconButton>
        }
        title={paleogenome.data[key].NAME}
        subheader={paleogenome.data[key].FULL_NAME}
      />
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I Would recommend you to write a function and return your CardHeader and you can try to write your loop there like;

loop{
   return(
          card
    )
}

that would be work ı guess, ı mostly render my components in functions.

Be safe bye :)

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` doesn't return anything, you must use `.map` and return the `<CardHeader>` component. In order for you components to be re-rendered they must be returned from inside a loop

```js
 {
    Object.keys(paleogenome.data).map(function (key){

      console.log(paleogenome.data[key].NAME); //PRINT WORKS FINE
      console.log(paleogenome.data[key].FULL_NAME); //PRINT WORKS FINE

      return <CardHeader
        avatar={
          <Avatar aria-label="recipe" className={classes.avatar}>
            R
          </Avatar>
        }
        action={
          <IconButton
            href={`/buscador?` + paleogenome.data[key].NAME}
          >
            <ArrowForwardIcon />
          </IconButton>
        }
        title={paleogenome.data[key].NAME}
        subheader={paleogenome.data[key].FULL_NAME}
      />


    })
}
```